# Output synchronization

Tags: python, process, locking, stdout

If a Python has a line:

```
print(message)
```

is there a way to make the message to always appear on standard output as whole?

There problem is that there might be some subprocesses or C extensions which could write to stdout in the same time.

In other words, if I want to `print()` something how to guarantee that it will end up in stdout non-interleaved with other outputs? Is this even possible? I know there is `multiprocessing.Lock` but that would require to pass the same lock around every `print` in subprocesses or extension, something I'm not sure if possible to do...

Answer (score 0):

In cPython for Python 2 the GIL,  global interpreter lock, will usually take care of this for you.

For sub-processes you can start them with stdout redirected and report at your convenience - most library C extensions would only normally give output to stdout in the event of a serious problem so should not be an issue.

If it is an issue - and I wouldn't worry too much until it is - why not replace all your print functions with a report function that uses Lock if needed - you could even replace the default print with such a class.

Comment: No, it wont: http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes

Comment: I wont start a subprocess, a user library may. Also, this is not Python 3 specific, see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes

Comment: Then override print to a print with lock.  If you are allowing __user__ libraries and need to ensure that your output doesn't get overwritten then start them in sub-processes which is probably safer anyway.